# Make cell range appear in different position to VLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I want to use `VLOOKUP` to search the highest value in a given range, and report to me what day it's the highest.

Example `VLOOKUP` for my actual data set in case if it matters:
`=VLOOKUP(MAX(A3:A1001),A3:B1001,2,FALSE)`

All I need to get this to work right, is a way to refer to the data in a way better than `A2:B6`.
I want to be able to take `A2:A6` and `B2:B6`, and treat them as if `A2:A6` is to the right of `B2:B6`. And I want to do this for several sets of data.

How I want to store my data:

[image]

How I want my data to appear to `VLOOKUP`:

[image]

How I may have to sort my data if I can't do this:

[image]

Example `VLOOKUP` for this data set:
`=VLOOKUP(MAX(A2:A6),A2:B6,2,FALSE)`

I don't want to do it by this brute force method, because it would add 119 additional duplicate columns to my actual data set, or 2 to this pseudo data set.

**TL;DR:** I want to be able to pass a cell range, without it being the real cell range, adjusting the positions of the columns.
Not sure if it's possible, and I don't technically need it to be this way, but it would make it significantly easier to look at.

Also, if there is a way to make `VLOOKUP` handle this correctly without making fake column positions that requires the `Day` column to be on the far right, that's acceptable, I just don't want a ton of duplicate columns in between real data.

Lastly, I also want to mention, it's very possible this entire problem exists simply because I don't understand `VLOOKUP` very well. I might be doing this completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Curly Brackets for this.

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(L2:L6),{L2:L6,K2:K6},2,FALSE)
```


You can even have more columns included

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(L2:L6),{L2:L6,K2:K6,M2:N6},2,FALSE)
```

You can read more about [Curly brackets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)